GET request in loop
I have a Nextjs and ts application, which makes a request that calls a webhook from an integration that returns a Google sheet in a json array, I noticed that it is requesting from my integration continuously in a loop.
My code:
import { useQuery, UseQueryResult } from "@tanstack/react-query";

const useFetchData = <T>(url: string, queryKey: string): UseQueryResult<T> => {
  return useQuery<T>({
    queryKey: [queryKey],
    queryFn: async () => {
      console.log(`Fetching data from: ${url}`);
      const response = await fetch(url);
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Network response was not ok: ${response.statusText}`);
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      console.log("Data fetched:", data);
      return data;
    },
  });
};

export default useFetchData;

I put logs and the page is not there being re-rendered again, only the request occurs again and again.I couldn't identify the reason for this.

You should use the staleTime and cacheTime options in useQuery to control the frequency of the requests. staleTime specifies how long the data is considered fresh, and cacheTime defines how long inactive data remains in the cache. Setting staleTime to a higher value will prevent the continuous refetching of the data. However, the main purpose of useQuery is to continuously fetch data as needed. If you want to fetch data only when a button is clicked or just on the first render, there is no need to use useQuery.
https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/framework/react/reference/useQuery
